# How do I require() web workers in npm?

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, webpack, web-worker

I've got a npm/webpack setup, and part of my application requires Web Workers. Normally, web workers are created with this syntax:

`var worker = new Worker('path/to/external/js/file.js');`

In npm, this doesn't work, because the development environment I'm using doesn't accept paths like this. Files must be included using `require()`.

I can't just link to the file absolutely, since that violates the cross-origin rule thing.

Is there a strategy for including these worker files?

Comment: Are you trying to run your web workers in *Node*?

Comment: Nope, I'm developing for the front end. Maybe this question is more suited to webpack, but I'm having trouble requiring the external worker file for inclusion in the package.

Comment: Well the `new Worker()` code runs on the client; it doesn't matter what Node or npm want, because as far as the server is concerned that code is just content. The worker file will be fetched from the client with a plain old HTTP request to the URL you pass to `new Worker()`.

Comment: Yep, problem is hosting on my dev environment. I can't just get files from the server setup I'm using, and I can't link an absolute path from elsewhere because CORS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [worker-loader](https://github.com/webpack/worker-loader) loader provided by Webpack seems to provide a solution to your problem. This module can be installed with `npm install --save-dev worker-loader`.

Take a look at [how to use loaders](https://webpack.js.org/concepts/loaders/#using-loaders), then require your web worker files like so:

```
const Foo = require("worker!./path/to/external/js/file.js");
const fooWorker = new Foo();
```

Note the `worker!` prepended before the path, which tells Webpack to use the worker loader specifically.

You should be able to require modules normally in the worker file itself also, provided your setup is correct.

Comment: Seems to be working! That was surprisingly easy. Thanks.